# How to use pytest to test a package installed from github

Tags: python, github, pip, pytest

I have installed a package from github using pip.

```
pip install git+'...'
```

The package is structured like this:

```
setup.py
pkg/
    app.py
    __init__.py
tests/
    test.py
    __init__.py
```

How can I run the tests from the tests folder using pytest on my machine?

Comment: You should be able to just run "pytest" now. There may be extra test dependencies needed to install, check the project README about that.

Comment: Just the command 'pytest'? It says no tests ran. I have no idea where to find the tests folder on my machine, I can find the pkg folder no problem

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you pip installed - but you'll need to clone the repo.  An installation generally doesn't install the tests too.

Comment: Thank you wim, that makes sense. Do you know if there is a way to run tests when installing with pip, or its not possible?

Comment: It used to be common to execute a test suite with `python setup.py test` but that's not generally done these days due to various issues. In fact I can't think of any project that still packages like that.